# Desktop changed to black?

Tags: raspbian

I was removing some bloat from the raspberry pi as all I need is the desktop with a browser (and SSH and VNC).

So I removed Libreoffice, the Java IDEs, some games etc. that I didn't need.

However, when I rebooted the desktop has changed from the raspbian white desktop to a weird black desktop with different task bar.

How can I get back to the ordinary raspbian desktop?

Comment: Debian (and therefore raspbian) can be so sensitive - it was probably something in the 'etc' that did it

Comment: @JaromandaX See my answer below :)

Comment: see ... it **was** something in the 'etc' that did it :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to fix it.

At some point during my uninstallation of bloat, I must have accidentally uninstalled the `raspberrypi-ui-mods` package. Reinstalling this package and rebooting brought me back the white default raspbian desktop I know and love.

So just run `sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-ui-mods` and reboot.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and "sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-ui-mods" helped me to get back to the default desktop. However, now I found the LXDE seems to be better. Is there a way to switch between them?